# Is There a General Formula for $\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\sum_{a=1}^b\left(c_ak^{a-1}\right)\right)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, power-series

all.

The other day, I was a bit bored so I started toying around with a function (I think) I invented which I'm calling the $\chi$ function such that $\chi(n, f(x))=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(k + if(k) \right)$. It's obvious that this can be reduced to $\chi(n, f(x)) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + i\sum_{k=1}^n(f(k))$ but what's a bit less obvious is how different functions being passed in for the parameter $f(x)$ affect its value. So far, I've managed to work out the cases for $f(x)=\log_bx$ and $f(x)=ae^x$ by myself. With the help of calculus YouTubers Flammable Maths and Dr Peynam, I also managed to crack $f(x)=\Pi(x)$ and $f(x)\in\{\cos x, \sin x, \tan x, \sec x, \csc x, \cot x\}$. The one I'm having a bit of trouble with is the generalised polynomial that I generated.

From what I can gather, a polynomial can be represented by $\sum_{a=1}^n\left(c_ax^{a-1} \right)$ where $c$ is a list of constants with $b$ elements. Naturally, this means that the imaginary part of the $\chi$ function would be represented by the following:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\sum_{a=1}^b\left(c_ak^{a-1} \right) \right)$$
I already experimented with a small sample size to see if the summations would be interchangeable and, unfortunately, they are not. After looking around online, I could only find articles and videos on generalised Power Series (nothing like this from what I saw) thus I was wondering if there is a generalised formula for what this would yield. I understand if it's too general, but maybe there's something I don't know.

The furthest my formal maths education went was Calc I, but I've since been trying to teach myself some more advanced stuff like Calc II, number theory (Collatz lived in my head rent-free for about four months), and functions on and about the Complex Plane so I would appreciate if things that may be trivial for anything above, say, First-Year Calc to be explained a bit slowly or link to vidoes/articles that explain the concept so that I can understand and learn from this.

Maths is a newfound interest of mine (only about two years) and I like playing around with silly or even trivial things because the sense of discovery (even if the proof is 2000 years old) is a great motivator to keep experimenting and exploring. I hope that you folks can help me here so that I can continue to learn and grow.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finite sums are always interchangeable:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left(c_1 k^0 + c_2 k^1 + \cdots + c_b k^{b-1} \right) = $$
$$c_1 \left(\sum_{k=1}^n k^0 \right) + c_2 \left(\sum_{k=1}^n k^1 \right) + \cdots + c_b \left(\sum_{k=1}^n k^{b-1} \right)$$

To work out the sums in the parentheses, you'll need Faulhaber's formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula, which regrettably does not have a closed form.

Comment: Ah... just as I feared. When I was able to solve/find ways to simplify the other expressions, I was confused as to why Polynomials (arguably the easiest to understand of the functions) were so difficult for me to work out into a generalise formula. Thanks for the link, it was a great help ^_^

Answer (score 2):

From a formal point of view, you can write

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{a=1}^b c_a\,k^{a-1}=\sum_{a=1}^b\sum_{k=1}^n  c_a\,k^{a-1}=\sum_{a=1}^b c_a \,H_n^{(1-a)}$$ where appear generalized harmonic numbers.